# Does sqlalchemy support mysql json_table() function?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, mysql-8.0

There is a sql like:
'SELECT j.element, count(distinct a.id) as cnt FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b ON b.aid=a.id JOIN JSON_TABLE(b.category, '$[*]' columns (element varchar(50) path '$')) j WHERE a.tech_platform=:tech_platform AND a.prod_id=:prod_id and a.biz_type=:biz_type and a.report_status like '报告%' and a.report_result=:report_result and j.element <> '' GROUP BY j.element;'

The field category is json array like: ['A', 'B', 'C'],

I want to convert the sql statement to an orm statement, but I failed, I'm not sure if the sqlalchemy support it?